# Vue.js Components not independent of each other

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I expected the component to be independent of each other and display  independent counters, but it is obviously not what is happening...

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <compteur> </compteur>
  <compteur> </compteur>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('compteur',{
  template: '<div>{{cptr}}</div>',
  data(){
    return {
     cptr:0
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    self = this;
    setInterval(function() {
    self.cptr +=1;
  }, 1000);
}
 })


 vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
 });
```

On top of that, if I only use one component , it counts by 1 which is fine but if I add a second one, the first one remains at 0 and the second one counts by 2.

Comment: `self = this;` self is global here. Don't use this pattern, use `bind()` instead `setInterval(function() {}.bind(this));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not declare `self`, it will be looked up as a property on `window` (as [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self)), then both component instances will be accessing the same `self` property on the `window` object.

Try declaring `self` with `const` or `let`:

```
let self = this;
```

Or better yet, just use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will automatically bind `this`:

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.cptr += 1;
}, 1000);
```